# Check all value of Object except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript.The object looks something like

```
{date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0}
```

Can I check to see if all values in object are `==0` except for the date?

I am not sure how I can go about coding that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to extract the date and the rest of the properties and calculate the `sum` of the [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) :

```js
const obj = { date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0 };

const { date, ...rest } = obj;

const sum = Object.values(rest).reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr, 0);
const allZeros = sum === 0 ? true : false;

console.log(allZeros);
```

( keep in mind that this will create a variable `date` in the current scope )

or, use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const obj = { date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0 };

const { date, ...rest } = obj;

const allZeros = Object.values(rest).every(e => e === 0);

console.log(allZeros);
```

Comment: I would use `.every(n => n === 0)` instead of summing all the values using `reduce` followed by checking if the sum is `0`. Also `sum === 0 ? true : false` is an ant-pattern and could just be `sum === 0`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yup, that would be better, i was thinking about it right when you commented.

Comment: @Taki, can we also do the same with json objects. Well the json has just one object `[{ date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0 }]

Comment: @noob , that's an array, you'll need to apply the above to each element, like `const {...} = obj[0]`, or inside a loop

Comment: @Taki, can you give an example. Sorry, I really am a noob at this

Comment: according to what you posted in your last comment, it's `const { date, ...rest } = obj[0];`

Comment: You also need to use the JSON.parse function before you can do anything as   true JSON will be just a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative that uses [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in combination with [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const allZeroExceptDate = o =>
    Object.entries(o).every(([k, v]) => k === "date" || v === 0);

console.log(allZeroExceptDate(
  {date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0}
));

console.log(allZeroExceptDate(
  {hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0}
));

console.log(allZeroExceptDate(
  {date: "some-date", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 33}
));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop over properties:

```
let obj = {date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0}
let isAllZero = true
for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'date' && obj[key] !== 0) {
        isAllZero = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let testObj = {date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0};
let result = true;
for(const key of Object.keys(testObj)) {
  if(key !== 'date' && testObj[key] !== 0) result = false;
}
return result;
```

We can loop through the keys of an object using `Object.keys(someObj)` and check if the key is equal to date. We can also perform the value checks in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor...in) with an if statement:

```js
var obj = {date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0};

for (var prop in obj) {
  if ((prop !== 'date') && (obj[prop] === 0)) {
    console.log("check for zero passed and NOT date");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is I think simplest answer, you can simply separate Object Keys & Values and than check "not date" and "equals to 0" in [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

```
let main_obj = {date: "2019-10-03", hello: 0, yo: 0, test: 0};

let obj_keys = Object.keys(main_obj);

let obj_values = Object.values(main_obj);

for(i = 1; i <= obj_keys.length; i++) {
    if(obj_keys[i] != 'date' && obj_values[i] == 0) {
        console.log('Found Zero Number ' + i);
    }
}
```